# Prolog, simple task

Tags: prolog

I got list of facts:

digit(0).
digit(1).
digit(2).
digit(3).
digit(4).
digit(5).
digit(6).
digit(7).
digit(8).
digit(9).

Now I have to create clause which will check whether given number as argument is single or double-digit. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use atom_codes/2. For instance, the following predicate holds for single digit number (in fact for any single character atom):

```
single_digit(N):-
atom_codes(N, List),
length(List,1).
```

Comment: also, `length(List,1)` === `List = [_]`, so together it's `atom_codes(N, [_])`. but your predicate is too permissive, it'll also succeed for `single_digit(a)`, but `a` is not a `digit` (i.e. `digit(a)` fails). :)